# Class for packing two 4 bit unsigned integer in uint8_t

Tags: c++17, integer

The purpose for this class is to pack two 4 bit unsigned integer into 8 bit unsigned integer, e.g. `uint8_t`.

It is made in a way, so the class to resemble array of two contiguous elements.

Once this work correctly, one may program continuous array of 4 bit integers and to use it for example for counting bloom filter.

A "special" proxy class is used in a way similar to std::vector, so you can do:

```
    UINT4 x;

    // set parts
    x[0] =  1; // set first  part, OK
    x[1] = 20; // set second part, OK

    // convert to uint8_t
    uint8_t i = x[0]; // OK

    // arithmetic mostly works.
    ++x[0]; // OK

    x[0] += 10; // OK

    --x[1]; // OK

    x[1] -= 10; // OK

    // not implemented yet, mostly because I don't need it
    // x[1] = x[0] + 10;
```

---

```
#include <cstdint>
//#include <type_traits>
//#include <cstdio>



class UINT4{
    uint8_t _0 : 4;
    uint8_t _1 : 4;

    class Proxy;

public:
    constexpr explicit UINT4() : UINT4{ 0, 0 }{
    }

    constexpr UINT4(uint8_t _0, uint8_t _1) : _0{ _0 }, _1{ _1 }{
    }

    constexpr
    Proxy operator[](std::size_t i);

    constexpr uint8_t operator[](std::size_t i) const{
            if (i == 0)
                return _0;
            else
                return _1;
    }
};

static_assert(sizeof(UINT4) == 1);



class UINT4::Proxy{
    UINT4 &d;
    uint8_t i;

public:
    // c-tor

    constexpr Proxy(UINT4 &d, std::size_t i) :
                                    d(d                 ),
                                    i(i == 0 ? 0 : 1    ){
    }

    // convert

    constexpr operator uint8_t() const{
        // we can use UINT4::operator[](size_t) const

        if (i == 0)
            return d._0;
        else
            return d._1;
    }

    // compare

    constexpr bool operator==(uint8_t x) const{
        if (i == 0)
            return d._0 == x;
        else
            return d._1 == x;
    }

    constexpr bool operator!=(uint8_t x) const{
        return !( *this == x );
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(uint8_t x) const{
        if (i == 0)
            return d._0 < x;
        else
            return d._1 < x;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<=(uint8_t x) const{
        if (i == 0)
            return d._0 <= x;
        else
            return d._1 <= x;
    }

    constexpr bool operator>(uint8_t x) const{
        return !( *this <= x );
    }

    constexpr bool operator>=(uint8_t x) const{
        return !( *this < x );
    }

    // assign

    constexpr
    auto &operator=(uint8_t x){
        if (i == 0)
            d._0 = x;
        else
            d._1 = x;

        return *this;
    }

    // +++

    constexpr
    auto &operator+=(uint8_t x){
        if (i == 0)
            d._0 += x;
        else
            d._1 += x;

        return *this;
    }

    constexpr
    auto &operator++(){
        return *this += uint8_t{ 1 };
    }

    // can not be done easily, because there are references
    // auto operator++(int);

    // ---

    constexpr
    auto &operator-=(uint8_t x){
        return *this += - x;
    }

    constexpr
    auto &operator--(){
        return *this -= uint8_t{ 1 };
    }

    // can not be done easily, because there are references
    // auto operator--(int);

    // todo add multiplication and division
};



constexpr auto UINT4::operator[](std::size_t i) -> Proxy{
    return Proxy{ *this, i };
}


#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    UINT4 x{ 15, 0 };
    x[1] = 2;

    uint8_t a = x[0];

    printf("%u\n", a);

    printf("%u %u\n", uint16_t{ x[0] }, uint16_t{ x[1] } );

    x[0] -= 10;
    x[1] += 10;

    printf("%u %u\n", uint16_t{ x[0] }, uint16_t{ x[1] } );

    ++x[0];
    --x[1];

    printf("%u %u\n", uint16_t{ x[0] }, uint16_t{ x[1] } );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Make it work like `std::vector<bool>`

Your class shares similarities with [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). I recommend that you make it work more like that. In particular, instead of just providing two 4-bit integers, make a class that acts like a vector of them. You already mentioned that the use case is for contiguous arrays, but if you have to write:

```
std::vector<UINT4> values;
```

Then it actually becomes very awkward to access the `n`-th 4-bit integer, because you'd have to write something like:

```
std::size_t n = …;
auto value = values[n / 2][n & 1];
```

Instead it would be much nicer to be able to write:

```
vector_uint4 values;
…
std::size_t n = …
auto value = values[n];
```

[`std::vector<bool>::reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) uses a proxy class just like your class. It is a bit simpler since it only needs to deal with operations that make sense for booleans. But note that it not only allows `bool` arguments, it also has overloads that take other `std::vector<bool>::reference`s as parameters. This allows you to, say, assign the value of one reference to another. You might want to allow something similar in your class, so you can add one 4-bit value of the vector to another one. Of course, if you are sure you are not going to need it, I would not implement that, but if you wanted to make a generic library that can be used for other purposes than your bloom filter, this is something you might want to think about.

Comment: Yes, I already have class similar to vector. I like this one `values[n / 2][n & 1]`